# How do I make a wooden toilet seat not splinter and last a long time?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, toilet, plumbing-fixture, bathroom-fixtures

I wish I had some photographs of the old toilet seat to show you, but the old wood toilet seat splintered and cracked. Humidity from the water in the toilet bowl probably caused the wood to rot.

How do I prevent this?

Comment: coat it with clear acrylic, aka clear spray paint.

Comment: Replace it with a metal one. keep it in a cupboard.

Answer (score -1):

It is probably too late for the existing splintered wood toilet seat.

However, after you buy a new wooden toilet seat, put the new wood toilet seat outside or in a garage.
Use varnish or spar urethane designed for use on wooden boats and / or wooden canoes.

The brand of varnish I have used in the past was named "Le Toikenois". Feel free to use a different brand of varnish or spar urethane. Any kind of varnish which is used on small wooden boats will work well on wooden toilet seats.

After the bad smelling fumes have gone away and at least 2 days have passed, touch the toilet seat with your fingers to feel if it is sticky.

Bolt the dry varnished toilet seat onto the toilet with two bolts.